# How to obtain the values of a list of objects within a Model in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two modes, User and Friends, it's a one-to-many relationship

I'm trying to get the values like this

```
record = User.query.filter_by(id=7).first()
```

These are the methods and properties that my model has:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', 
   __eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',   
  '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', 
  '__le__','__lt__','__mapper__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', 
  '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
  '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__table__', 
  '__tablename__', '__weakref__', '_decl_class_registry', 
  '_sa_class_manager', '_sa_instance_state','id', 'rfc', 'name', 
  'friends']
```

`friends` is the array that I want to get their values

```
print('|{}|{}|{}'.format(record.user.rfc,
     record.user.name,
     record.friends
    )
)
|BDS344XX3343|Bob|[<models.Friend object at 0x7f0276752e48>,
 <models.Friend object at 0x7f0276752eb8>
```

Any idea or suggestion to get the values of `friends`

Comment: Can you inspect the `record.friends[0]` object and provide the attributes and methods?

Comment: Rather than show that useless printout of the `dir()`, you should show the model definition. What is `friends` - is it a relationship field of some kind? And what exactly do you mean by "the values of friends" - if it's another model, what fields do you want to show?

Comment: From the looks of it you already got the value: a list of `Friend` objects. So what's the problem? Are you asking about how to use lists in Python?

Comment: @James It has the same methods and attributes as User, for example in friends: 'name', 'lastname' ...

Comment: @IljaEverilä  The problem is that I want to access the values of friends as in the user, it is a one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to pull the `name` and `lastname` attributes out of each of the `friend` objects that are contained in the list assigned to `record.friends`.

This (should) create a single string of all the friends' name and last name joined with an ampersand.

```
print('|{}|{}|{}'.format(record.user.rfc,
     record.user.name,
     '& '.join('{} {}'.format(f.name, f.lastname) for f in record.friends)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking exactly this!!!